# Sort by parity in rust

Tags: sorting, rust

I am learning sorting in rust. I want to sort vector as such that even numbers go first

My code is OK. But can it be improved (I want to use sort function)?

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 10, 4, 3];
    v.sort_by(|a, b | {
        (a % 2).cmp(&(b % 2))
    });
    println!("{:?}", v); // [1, 2, 10, 4, 3]

}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. But that's an odd comparison function, which discards all the high-order bits. You're sure you wouldn't care to use magnitude as a tie breaker? I mean, you have the first half of a [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), assigning to one of two buckets. But the "sort within bucket" part is missing.

Comment: `v.sort_by_key(|v| v % 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Partition the Array

This is the standard example of [`std::iter::Iterator::partition`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition).  There is also a nightly experimental `partition_in_place`.

```rust
let (even, odd): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = a
    .into_iter()
    .partition(|n| n % 2 == 0);
```

This runs in *O*(*N*) time, while sorting takes *O*(*N* log *N*) time.

If you want the `even` and `odd` collections to be sorted (which this doesn’t do), it’s more efficient to partition and then sort the sub-arrays.  Sorting has worse-than-linear time complexity, so it’s better to sort two partitions than one large array.

Answer (score 1):

### `x % 2` has a nasty pitfall

And it results in a bug this time.

How much is `-1 % 2`? It couldn't be 0 of course, but it's also not 1. Not in Rust anyway, it does vary by language.

With this data: `let mut v = vec![1, 2, 10, 4, 3, -1, -2, -3];`, I get this result:

```
[-1, -3, 2, 10, 4, -2, 1, 3]
```

Probably not what you want.

On the other hand, `x & 1` properly results in 0 for even numbers and 1 for odd numbers, positive or negative.

Using `x % 2` to decide even/odd is not always wrong. If the result is compared to zero, it doesn't matter that odd numbers sometimes result in +1 and sometimes in -1, either way the result isn't zero. That's why Davislors answer doesn't suffer from this bug, despite using `n % 2`.

Comment: Or `x.rem_euclid(2)`.

Comment: Rustc with release flags optimizes `n%2 == 0`, into a bitwise and, automatically. So, yes, they’re equivalent.

Comment: Also, like I said in my answer, that’s not my code. It’s an example from the Rust standard library documentation I linked to.

Comment: But, flattered that you’d give me credit for it!